# How to reset values when use click button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have this html and jQuery which helps to get the values in a div in order the buttons are clicked and they are working fine. By some means I want to reverse the functionality so that I can deselect and choose something else in it's place.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">. 
</script>
<div class="demo"></div>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="one" class="vehicle" value="car">Car</button>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="two" class="vehicle" value="bus">Bus</button>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="three" class="vehicle" value="truck">Truck</button>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="four" class="vehicle" value="copter">Copter</button>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="five" class="vehicle" value="train">Train</button>

(function($){
jQuery.fn.isEmpty = function() {
   return !$.trim(this.html()).length;
};
}(jQuery));

$("button.vehicle").click(function() {
$(this).addClass("selected");
const limit = 3, sep = ',', $demos = $(".demo");
if($demos.html().split(sep).length < limit){
$demos.append(($demos.isEmpty() ? '' : sep) + $(this).val());
}
});

$(function() {
var click = 0;
$("button.vehicle").click(function(){
if (click <  3) {
$(this).prev().show();
var current = $(this).prev().text();
var existingClicks = current.split(" ");
if(existingClicks.length > 1) {
$(this).prev().text(current+" &"+(++click))
$(this).prev().append("<button class='reset'>X</button>");
}
else {
$(this).prev().text(" "+(++click))
$(this).prev().append("<button class='reset'>X</button>");
}
}
})
})
```

As I click any button then it outputs the respective values in  and also shows at which order the buttons are clicked. I am trying to add an "x" button next to order number so that by clicking on it I can reset the value in div and also that particular order number and can select something else at it's place.

For example:- If I clicked "Car" for the first and third number and "Truck" at second number then it will output the values as Car, Truck, Car. Now if I want to change second value to Bus then I should be able to reset the click on "Truck" and select "Bus" at second number and this button will then show 2 signifying that it's the second number selection.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to consider using `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following alternative.

```js
$(function() {
  var selected = [];

  $("button.vehicle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      if (selected.length < 3) {
        // Add Value to end
        selected.push($(this).val());
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // Remove Value
      selected.splice(selected.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
    }
    $(".demo").html(selected.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="three" class="vehicle" value="truck">Truck</button>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="four" class="vehicle" value="copter">Copter</button>
<div class="clicked-order"></div>
<button id="five" class="vehicle" value="train">Train</button>

<div class="demo"></div>
```

This keeps an Array for Selected items. Using `.toggleClass()` we can add or remove the Class on each Click. We can them perform specific actions depending on the status of the click.

The Click will Add or Remove the selected button.